# DirectShow fullscreen video player upscale quality

Tags: video, directshow, scale

I'm building graph using method

```
IGraphBuilder::RenderFile
```

And query interfaces IMediaControl - to run video and IVideoWindow - to set fullscreen.

Everything is ok but video quality - seems like d3d is not using linear filter for upscaling (if thats actually underneath - not sure).

Anyone knows if there is a way to have a good video upscale quality with such graph building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Vista and Windows 7 you have to use [`Enhanced Video Renderer Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as video renderer in order to enable Driect3D smooth scaling. Default renderer does not get you that (it does in Windows XP though).

This makes you built your graph manually, not just with `RenderFile`, and you also have to use windowless mode since EVR does not offer you `IVideoWindow`. Other than this, EVR is similar to VMR-9.

Comment: Thx, my fears came true. Such a nice short code just to play a cutscene, have to grow now :/